# Ajaxing user controls from client code (using telerik)

Tags: asp.net, ajax, user-controls, telerik

To clarify, by 'client code' I mean the code that has my control instance (not client as in javascript)

I'd like for the client of my custom user control to specify whether it's inner-controls when its being used. So for example, 1 instance could operate over AJAX and another could post back regularly.

I already have the AJAX working if I place the ajax code within the User Control and specifically say the 'innerList' is the AjaxControlID, but it would be better if the client code specified it.

Test.aspx:

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManager runat="server" ID="RadAjaxManager1" >
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="testID">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="testID"/>
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>

<testing:MyTestUserControl id="testID" runat="server" />
```

MyTestUserControl.ascx:

```
<asp:DropDownList id="innerList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" >
    <Items><ListItem text="textItem"></ListItem></Items>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want certain instances to perform full postbacks you can simply disable the AJAX functionality: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/ajax-forcing-postback.html. Or simply set the server-side EnableAJAX property of the manager to false.